# Can I run Dragon NaturallySpeaking on Amazon WorkSpaces?

Tags: amazon-web-services, remote-access, remote-server, naturallyspeaking

I use Dragon dictation software including by using it over a remote access to my home computer.  I also once had it set up on the network server computer at a client site which I could also access when logged in remotely.  But now, I have a situation where my access to work info is over Amazon WorkSpaces.  Does anyone know if Dragon Pro can be installed on and accessed through an Amazon WorkSpace desktop?

TIA!!

Comment: If you could access WorkSpaces via RDP, you could dictate with Dragon Pro through RDP. As that is not possible (https://aws.amazon.com/workspaces/faqs/#Clients_User_Experience), you'd need to check if you can route your microphone somehow directly to the WorkSpace as you would a USB device. The above link suggests it should be possible but you'd have to try it.

Comment: I have installed and can use Dragon, but recognition is poor.  AWS is using the "Teradici Virtual Audio Driver" and it seems to pick up sound that isn't too bad (using Sound Recorder) but it is really bad for speech recognition.  What can I do?  The driver seems to be a common one for VMware-style remote machines, and appears to be set up as "1 channel, 16 bit, 48000 Hz (DVD Quality)" as the Default Format (which should work for Dragon). Is there a way to map mu local USB microphone to the remote machine?

Comment: Hi PGilm, for the future, if you find somebody using the "Post Your Answer" on one of your questions, but what they post is instead a question, please make that user aware of their mistake, instead of teaching them an unwanted lesson by giving them an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your question was bugging me for a long time, finally I gave in and rented a WorkSpace and tried Dragon.

Recognition for me is totally fine as long as your local computer's standard audio input device is actually the one you want to use Dragon with. If your default input device is the built-in micro of your laptop, computer or screen, recognition will most likely be bad. I used a Sennheiser MB Pro 2 with a USB dongle on a Windows machine for testing, as well as a TravelMike with a USB MultiAdapter. Both work fine.

As for factors that influence recognition quality:

- I know from other virtualization/remote desktop solutions that the codec that transfers your speech to the virtual/remote machine may work well for one microphone, and not for others. Try a different mike and see if that improves your recognition.
- In order to rule out microphone issues, I suggest trying different internet connections (WiFi, Ethernet, tethering, different internet providers). Missing words from speech recognition over remote connections can indicate unstable or slow internet.

As far as I know, there is no way to patch a USB device through to the remote WorkSpaces machine.  What you could try is install a VPN on the remote machine and use your smartphone as a remote microphone in Dragon. Your smartphone also needs the VPN. If you get that to work, recognition should be as good as on your local network, given that internet connection is fast and stable enough.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful.  My mic is the Speechware USB TravelMike and SpeechMatic Usb MultiAdapter on my laptop.  I can try a different mic -- I have heard that direct to the motherboard soundcard or other soundcard (I have a SondBlaster on my rig) is better than a USB soundcard, but you say you've had success with a USB mic.  Hmmm.  Mine gives excellent sound for SoundRecorder, but the Dragon recognition is sketchy (lots of missing words, rather than outright mistakes).  I do use my Android SmartPhone as a microphone on my local set up, so I will try to see if the VPN solution works.  Thx,

Comment: @PGilm I've tested with TravelMike and MultiAdapter as well. It works, too. As for soundcards I exclusively use USB because it is so much easier to support and 3.5-mm-jacks are more susceptible to noise from vibrations within the computer.